# Hi can anyone help me with an example of List<File> in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanna add selected images to this list `List<File>`. Im using a WYSIWYG editor.Everytime a user selects an image,I wanna store the image files in a list called `List<File>` and later upload them to firebase when the user clicks on some button. This is where the selecting image happens.

```
Future<String> _onImagePickCallback(File file) async {
    if (file == null) return null;
    //  add to list<File>
  }
```

Comment: please add some more code

Answer (score 0):

First you should create the empty list:

```dart
List<File> images = [];
```

Then, inside the _onImagePickCallback add the file you get to the list:

```dart
images.add(file);
```

Later you can iterate through that list with a for or for-in loop to get the files out of the list and upload them. Or you can access the files inside the list by providing it with an index:

```dart
File image = images[0];
```